# want to display results from time_ago_in_words as “days ago”

Tags: ruby-on-rails, timestamp

I have something like this

```
   `@something= @something.each_with_index do |c, i|
    @something[i]['created_at']=time_ago_in_words(Time.new(c['created_at'])
```

`    and output is - 10 months 
    but i want the output as - 10 months ago 
    any suggestion would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add this

```
@something= @something.each_with_index do |c, i|
@something[i]['created_at']=time_ago_in_words(Time.new(c['created_at']) + "ago."
```